# Filter root element of tag cloud block

Tags: block-editor

By default the `tag-cloud` block in the (Gutenberg) block-editor renders a root element as follows:

```
<p class="wp-block-tag-cloud">...</p>
```

This is the corresponding code what is renders the block:
https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/blocks/tag-cloud.php#L44

Filtering with `pre_render_block` doesn't work.

Any idea how to filter this root element of this block?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself after all.

Instead of using the `pre_render_block` filter, use the [`render_block`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/render_block/) filter to do something like this:

```
add_filter('render_block', function($html, $block) {
    if ($block['blockName'] !== 'core/tag-cloud') {
        return $html;
    }

    $doc = new \DOMDocument($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
    $ps = iterator_to_array($doc->getElementsByTagName('p'));
    $p = empty($ps) ? new \DOMElement('p') : current($ps);

    return replaceChild($doc, $p, 'div', ['class' => 'tags'])->saveHTML();
}, 10, 2);

function replaceChild(\DOMDocument $doc, \DOMElement $target, string $tag, array $attrs = []) {
    $replacement = $doc->createElement($tag);

    if (!empty($attrs)) {
        foreach ($attrs as $key => $value) {
            $replacement->setAttribute($key, $value);
        }
    }

    if ($target->hasChildNodes()) {
        $children = iterator_to_array($target->childNodes);
        foreach ($children as $child) {
            $replacement->appendChild($child);
        }
    }

    $target->parentNode->replaceChild($replacement, $target);

    return $doc;
}
```

This should yield something like `<div class="tags">...</div>`.